# error code 400 while consuming svc service in ios using swift

Tags: ios, wcf, swift, svc

I am making a call to service as following using swift in ios,
My service is working perfectly fine with android version but when i try to make it work with ios it always return error code 400

below is the code of ios version

```
 var soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'><soap:Body><GetAirports xmlns='http://groundspan.com/groundspan'/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

   // var urlString = "http://example.com/myeservice.svc"
    var urlString = "http://example.com/myservice.svc?"
    var nameSpace = "http://example.com/service"
    var methodNam = "GetAirports"
    var msgLength = String(countElements(soapMessage))
    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    println("Url : \(url)")
    var theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    theRequest.addValue("http://example.com/service/IGroundSpanProcessorService/\(methodNam)", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
    theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)


    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
    connection?.start()

    if (connection == true) {
        var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
    }else{
        println("Error in connection")
    }
```

it always goes in to else block of connection and fives error in connection & also get error code 400 error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is going inside the "Error in connection" block however a few days back i had to deal with error 400 Bad Request (i imagine it means that one). 
First you should use a sniffer like Wireshark (i have also seen Fiddler recomended here a lot) to check the message you are sending and what you are getting from the server. This might help you see if you are receiving some fault which WCF doesn't parse automaticly.

Comment: if (connection != nil) {
        
    }
solved my problem of going in else block & also see below answer which solved error 400

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer to my own question

```
var soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'><soap:Body><GetAirports xmlns='http://example.com/example'/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

    var urlString = "http://example.com/GroundSpanProcessorService.svc"

    var msgLength = String(countElements(soapMessage))
    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    var theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    theRequest.addValue("http://example.com/example/IGroundSpanProcessorService/GetAirports", forHTTPHeaderField: "Soapaction")
    theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)


    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self,startImmediately: true)
    connection?.start()

    if (connection == true) {
        println("Connection success")
        var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
    }else{
        println("Error in connection")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution is first map the soap envelope perfectly then parse wsdl

var is_SoapMessage:String  = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>http://tempuri.org/'>"

```
var myelement :String = ""
var elementValue: String?
var success = false
var array_string = [String]()


// on click 


    var is_URL: String =  "http://assetwebservice.sudesi.in/service.svc"

    var lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: is_URL)!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var err: NSError?

    lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    lobj_Request.HTTPBody = is_SoapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    lobj_Request.addValue(String(count(is_SoapMessage)), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    //lobj_Request.addValue("223", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    lobj_Request.addValue("http://tempuri.org/IService/BindCategory", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in



    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

      //  println("Body:---- \(strData)")
        let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()

                          // Just in case, if there's an error, report it. (We don't want
        if error != nil
        {
            println("Error: " + error.description)
        }

    })
    task.resume()

}


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    println("first case ")
    println(elementName)

    if elementName == "GetDataResponse" {
        elementValue = String()
    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {


   println("second  case ")
    array_string.append(string!)
    anstext.text = string


   println(string)

    if elementValue != nil {

        println("come in this part ")
        elementValue! += string!
        array_string.append(elementValue!)


    }
    println((array_string.count))




}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?
    ) {

        println("third case ")


    if elementName == "GetDataResponse" {

        if elementValue == "true" {
            success = true
                      // println("this is right answer ")
```

print result here 
            }
            elementValue = nil
        }
    }

Thanks then get result